# Loading image from phone's album into ImageView does not work

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am trying to load an image from Phone's album into an ImageView. Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
            filename = intent.getExtras().getString("file");
            assert filename != null;
            File f = new File(filename);

            Picasso.with(AddCaptionActivity.this)
                    .load(f)
                    .into(image);
```

Running this code on most android phones works perfectly fine. But on one Android One phone running Android 6, the image does not load at all. Loading an image from Url from web into same imageView on the same phone works, but loading from album does not work.

I also get these in the logcat during this process:

```
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
```

I also tried to do the same thing using [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) library and that too didn't work.

What could be the reason for this kind of behaviour and how can I fix this?

Comment: Since you mentioned Android 6... Have you handled storage permissions on the app? Since it is runtime permission on android 6, you can try to goto app settings and turn ON the storage permission. All this, only if you have made your app with targetSDK 23. BTW I don't have any idea on the logcat that you posted. sorry

Comment: @abat I just tried that and it works perfectly fine. The problem, however, that I see now is, the app requests external storage permission but that permission was not given, even when I installed the app using adb. Is there any way to necessarily ask for that permission if the user wants to use the app?

Comment: Did you add the permission to access your phone photos in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @AmineLeo yes, I have added it.

Comment: @AmitTiwari You should read about handling permissions in your app at runtime. http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html It is easy. you just have to check this case for Marshmallow... the code samples in that link will help you

Comment: @abat thanks. I saw that one and implemented it. works fine now.